# Connect internet on Ubuntu virtualbox

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, internet

I want to use a bridged adapter to have 2 different IP addresses on 2 virtual machines, but when my PC connects to Wifi, my virtual machine can't connect to the internet, and it can only connect when using NAT, so how can I connect to the internet while using Wifi, but have 2 virtual machines have 2 different IP addresses? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Do the VMs need to be accessed by other computers on your network? Or are the VMs connected to only by the host/other VMs?

Comment: Once you selected bridge adapter, does VMs has given IPs ? if yes please ping 8.8.8.8 and check the connectivity.

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @matigo I have two virtual machines installed on my PC, and I want to use two different IP addresses on the machines. With NAT, it's only the same IP. With a bridge adapter, it's OK but cannot connect to the internet if my PC uses Wifi.

Comment: @zabiullah, yes, it's give me IPs. but cannot ping to 8.8.8.8

Comment: @David I am using 18.04

Comment: Does it ping its gateway?